# in app purchase not working Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm trying to make a non-consumable in app purchase in Swift in my app and when I run the app directly to my phone, the app does not crash, but when I download the app from the app store, the app crashes when I try to get an in app purchase.

This is the code.

```
var product = SKProduct()
SoundtrackPremium.store.requestProducts({ (success, products) in
    if success {
        product = products![0]
        // buy the product
        SoundtrackPremium.store.buyProduct(product)
    }
 })
```

The only thing I can think of is that the app update for the in app purchase just got approved. Does the in app purchasing take time to process to happen?

Comment: Where does it crash? Presumably at 'product = products![0]'? As an aside, using ! like this is generally a bad idea - even if Apple assure you that 'products' should not be nil at this point, users hate crashes and you should unwrap it and fail gracefully just in case.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely scenario is that you forgot to submit your IAP product for review with your app release.

IAP products are usually accessible in sandbox from the moment they are created but they need to be submitted for review before they are accessible in production i.e. the app store.

You can see [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingInAppPurchases.html) for instructions on submitting an IAP for review. Fortunately, if you submit the IAP for review now, it will be available in your app as soon as it is reviewed and your app should stop crashing.